# How to prove: Are perpendicular coordinates (wrt to relative velocity) unchanged (or only scaled) while deriving the Lorentz Transformations?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, spacetime, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

Thank you for helping with this question and I'm sorry if it's kind of stupid.

**TLDR**: In many textbooks and other derivations deriving the Lorentz Transformations, they omit coordinate axes orthogonal to the velocity vector between the inertial coordinate systems for brevity. (E.g. If $I'$ is moving (in frame $I$) with velocity $v$ in the positive $x$ direction, then coordinates $y$ and $z$ are omitted.) Intuitively I can convince myself makes sense, but how can one prove it rigorously?

**Long explanation**:
I've been trying to derive the Lorentz Transformations without using the Light Postulate sort of like the Ignatowski Transformations. I am following this broad scheme, credits to Brown's book Physical Relativity among other resources:

**1. Relativity Principle**: transformations between inertial coordinate systems must form a group (map straight lines to straight lines), and so must be of the form

$x'^\mu=\frac{(a^\mu_\nu)x^\nu+a^\mu}{(b^\mu_\nu)x^\nu+b^\mu}$ using Einstein Summation convention with
$\nu,\mu=0,1,2,3$ ($0$ for the $t$ coordinate)

**2. Finite** coordinates must always be taken to finite coordinates: Denominator must not depend on the coordinates, and through abuse of notation

$x'^\mu=(a^\mu_\nu)x^\nu+a^\mu$

**3.** For practicality, $I$ and $I'$ **coincide** at $t=0$:

$x'^\mu=(a^\mu_\nu)x^\nu$

The issue I'm having now is that many authors (Brown included) **jump straight to the following**:

$x'=k(v)(x-vt)$
$y'=f(v)y$
$z'=g(v)(z)$
$t'=h(v)x+l(v)t$

On what (rigorous) grounds is $y$ and $z$ **omitted** from, say, the first equation. **Why is it not instead: $x'=k(v)(x-vt)+m(v)y+n(v)z$ as concluded at the end of point 3?**

If it helps, one of the reasons that I'm searching for a rigorous solution is that I've had a lot of my physical intuitions shattered recently regarding derivations about the Lorentz Contractions. For example, the fact that there is so much work that one needs to do to get to the reciprocity principle (that if $I'$ travels with velocity $\vec{v}$ in I, then I travels with velocity $\vec{-v}$ in I'), or that the generalised Galilean coordinate transformations allow tilted simultaneity surfaces that still satisfy Newton's first law (e.g. a coordinate system that uses $t'=t-\alpha t$). **In light of this, I just want to find a sure-fire rigorous way to justify this.**

Thank you very much for your help. If any point is unclear (which some probably are), please don't hesitate to comment and I will try my best to edit it.

Comment: *are parallel coordinates unchanged* Parallel to what? Did you mean to write *perpendicular* to the relative velocity?

Comment: *so must be linear* The transformation below that isn’t linear. And nonlinear transformations can form a group.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've edited it to make it more clear/correct mistakes

Comment: You are concerned with rigorous logical thinking. Usually, physicists do not go so far with the exception of experts probably in relativity or QFT. I suspect Ignatowski's approach is interesting and rigorous, see for instance https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343096377_Relativity_without_light_A_new_proof_of_Ignatowski's_theorem

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your concern with the light postulate(LP). It gives a false impression (to beginners and aficionados) that relativity is only about the propagation of light. Relativity theory is about the existence of a universal finite velocity, the velocity of the physical interactions. According to relativity, all physical interactions happen at a finite speed c, in particular, electromagnetic and gravitational interactions.
When $c=\infty$, we have Newtonian mechanics, when $c\rightarrow\infty$ the Lorentz transformations (LT) reduce to Galilean transformations.
So from a purely physical viewpoint, it is essential to assume the "light postulate".

From the mathematical viewpoint, it is indeed possible to derive the LT in a rigorous way. One approach is the following:
The LP implies that if $ds=0$ in one inertial reference frame (IRF) then we must have $ds=0$ in all IRFs. If we only assume this we are led to the conformal group.
However, if we also assume homogeneity and isotropy of space and homogeneity of time we are led to $ds=invariant$ for all IRFs.
It is possible to prove that the invariance of $ds$ implies the linearity of the transformations. Then, a long series of algebraic manipulations allows one to derive the LT in a rigorous way without assuming $y'=y$ and $z'=z$.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the transformation is necessarily linear, even though peculiar thing happens in special relativity, we should not see something accelerate in different uniformly moving frames, if in one of the inertial frames this thing is stationary or uniformly moving.
The reason $y$ transformation does not have a time-dependent part: your motion is perpendicular to it and there is no way to distinguish time along y-axis, that is to say since everything happens in x, time is redundant in y.

Answer (score -2):

Oh, the physically pleasing way is to consider some physics and use that to fix this. In Chinese there is a rather nice physical motivation as to why y and z should stay unchanged.

Consider two grim reapers of the same height and holding their scythes out such that if both of them were stationary, the blades will pass just above the heads of the other one. i.e. if any of them were taller or shorter, someone will get hurt.

Now, if you put them on trains passing by each other in opposite directions at the same speed, then you would be unable to explain which one is the one that gets hurt. So neither can get hurt and the blades must collide.

The English versions are about painting lines on walls and being able to compare them later. Same result.